# How do I add style inline the color code which I m getting from an array of object

Tags: reactjs

Suppose my array of object is like this ms=[{id : 1 , Name : a , color : #333} {id : 2 , Name : b , color : #666} {id : 3 , Name : c , color : #ddd}]

Now my return in functional component

```
ms.map((eachname, index)=>
{
 <div classname = mainbloc>
   <div classname = insideblock style=. 
     {{borderRight: 1px solid ###}}>
      {eachname.Name}
   </div>
 </div>
})
```

I want to add the color of each object in the border right ### place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `template strings` to embed javascript expressions or values between strings. You can do something like this.

```
  ms.map((eachname, index) => (
    <div classname="mainblock" key={index}>
      <div
        classname="insideblock"
        style={{ borderRight: `1px solid ${eachname.color}` }}
      >
        {eachname.Name}
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
```

More information on template string:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

In case, for some reason, you don't want to use template strings you can use:

```
style={{
    borderRightWidth: 1, 
    borderRightWidth: 'solid', 
    borderRightColor: eachname.color, 
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use styled components if you don't want to use inline styling and make component more reusable and readable. More information [Styled components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics)

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
 borderRight: ${props => props.color}
`

 ms.map((eachname, index) => (
  <div classname="mainblock" key={index}>
   <StyledDiv color={eachname.color}>
    {eachname.Name}
   </StyledDiv>
  </div>
));
```